# Relative path using setImageResource

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to display an image in my app that changes everytime I press a button. 
The name of the image that should be shown is in my object. I can get the name of the image with

```
String nameOfImage = myObhect.get(i).getImageName();
```

Now, I want to display the current image with

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.notruf);
```

Using `setImageResource` , I don´t know how to bring the name of my image in  `setImageResource` because, for example

`iv.setImageResource(R.drawable. + aktbild)` isn´t possible for sure.

I also tried the way with `setImageDrawable` but that does not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use similar solution in my application :

```
Context mContext = this;  // I supposed you're in Activity
String imgName = fragenkatalog.get(i).getBild();
int resId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(imgName,
                        "drawable", mContext.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
if(resId > 0){
    iv.setImageResource(resId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is mContext?

Comment: mContext is your Activity/Context

Comment: The name of my Activity is Bronze (public class Bronze extends Activity), Bronze.getResources().... does not work. Am I wrong in my way?

Comment: it's not a static class. If you're in BronzeActivity, try this : `getResources()` directly

Comment: ok, with this.getResources() it works. But there´s still a problem with showing the image. I´ll make a few test output and come back then.

Answer (score 0):

**I believe that this code will help u..**

```
String aktbild = fragenkatalog.get(i).getBild();
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(aktbild , Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,
decodedString.length);
```

**After that, if you want to resize that image use this code.**

```
int width=75;
int height=75;
Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodedByte, width, height, true);
```

**finally set image into ImageView.**

```
Icon.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);`
```